# collapsing icon/text to just icon on left nav

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jsFiddle on this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nc5e2rtq/4/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="shrink" value="<" />
<div id="skaLeftNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="skaButton cf" nowrap="nowrap">
            <div class="skaImgWrap">
                img
            </div>
            <div class="skaTextWrap">My&nbsp;Dashboard&nbsp;Link1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="skaButton cf" nowrap="nowrap">
            <div class="skaImgWrap">
                img
            </div>
            <div class="skaTextWrap">My&nbsp;Dashboard&nbsp;Link2</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the js, pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shrink').click(function(){
        setTimeout($('#skaLeftNav').animate({width:50},2000),2000);
        $('.skaTextWrap').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```

and the part I'm most unsure about, the CSS:

```
#skaLeftNav{
    width:190px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
#skaLeftNav ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-left:none;
    }
.skaButton{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:70px;
    }
.skaImgWrap{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid gray;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    }
.skaTextWrap{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

The only (and obvious) problem I'm experiencing is that as the left nav narrows, the text block stacks under the image block.  BTW I specified height:75px for the <li> only so you could see what's happening.

Basically I'm struggling with the right display type and overflow type (if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
.skaButton {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; /* <- add this */
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/nc5e2rtq/6/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of Arbel is absolutely right. Just for documentation, you could also do something like this in your animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shrink').click(function(){
        setTimeout($('#skaLeftNav').animate({width:50},2000),2000);
        $('.skaTextWrap').animate({width:-5, opacity: 0},2000);
    });
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/ak5wvpfL/